# How to install Anaconda as a portable installation on a USB

Tags: usb, anaconda, portability

I've looked everywhere for a beginner-friendly guide on how to install Anaconda on a USB locally, but to no avail.

I'm currently using WinPython as an alternative, however, I get many errors when using Tkinter for my projects. I tried to see if it would give me an error after importing `turtle` and running basic code, but it returns `AttributeError: module 'turtle' has no attribute 'Turtle'` when it would otherwise work on my desktop.

Comment: I've been looking to do the same. The best I've found so far is this discussion with people trying to hack it themselves, but unfortunately there is no official support for this: https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/d/topic/anaconda/tiTwrmjbp1E/discussion

Answer (score 3):

**Explanation:**

You might be having two conda installed(not env, but the conda navigator) in your machine

- The default path to conda will be the on the C: drive of your computer

When you create a env, it will then dowload automaticly on your C: not on your new downloaded anaconda

- You can't activate the new env with it's name, the machine will name the env to "base", which is the same to your other default env in your original machine. It will crash and left your env with no name.

**Solve:**

You can activate the env with not only the name, the other way is activate with the path

`conda activate pathofenv`

**More detail**

1. Install anaconda on the usb stick

-remember to set the installation location to the stick

-The installation takes a amazing long time(for me 30min)

2. After instalation has finished, open cmd

Finally to activate the env You just need to type `conda activate thepathofenv`

This worked for me and hope it;ll work for you too :)

.sorry for typo